# Why does glScaled(1, 1, 5) change the lighting of a glVertex3d(1, 1, 0)?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, opengl

I'm drawing 2 triangles at `z=0` with diffuse lighting centered from above. If I scale one of them in the `z` axis, it changes its lighting. Since `z=0`, I would have thought that scaling in the z axis would have no effect.

What am I missing?

---

### Rendering Code

```
  // Set up the a light centered horizontally.
  glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
  glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
  float light1Position[] = { 0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
  float light1Diffuse[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light1Position);
  glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light1Diffuse);

  // Set up the material.
  float material1Diffuse[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
  glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, material1Diffuse);

  // Transform such that we can draw in (-1, -1) to (1, 1) at z = 0.
  glTranslated(0, 0, -1);
  glScaled(2, 2, 1);

  // Draw two triangles, symmetric w.r.t. to the light and camera.
  glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex3d(-1, -1,  0);
    glVertex3d( 0,  1,  0);
    glVertex3d(-1,  1,  0);
  glEnd();

  glScaled(1, 1, 5.0);  // This should be a no-op since 5 * 0 = 0.
                        // However, the following triangle is darker.
  glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex3d( 1, -1,  0);
    glVertex3d( 1,  1,  0);
    glVertex3d( 0,  1,  0);
  glEnd();
```

---

### Rendering Result

[image: screenshot]

---

I've uploaded a Cocoa project that repros this [on github](https://github.com/bklimt/Repro3D/blob/master/Repro3D/Repro3D/BKOpenGLView.m). I've tried this in both Objective-C and C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though the coordinates of your vertices are 0 in the Z direction, your normals aren't necessarily. In fact, the default normal is (0, 0, 1), which is in effect since you don't specify any normals explicitly in your sample code.

Therefore, your problem is that the normal is being scaled to a non-normalized length by your `glScale` matrix.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize OpenGL normals could be non unit-length. Adding glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE) fixed it.